# Paypal implementation...c++

Tags: java, php, c++, paypal

A paypal website has to be programmed. It is a website that allows to exchange money between users through paypal.

1 - How do I do this? 
2 - I spoke with a very skilled programmer and he told me that in order to get the thing to work in your own app you needed to implement this in c++. A pity I could not speak more with him.
EDIT: The same programmer told me it could be also written in Java.

I will appreciate all opinions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lucky you didn't speak more with that person, because it doesn't sound like they know what they're talking about. Try starting [here](https://cms.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_overview)

Comment: There's [an entire website](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal) dedicated to what you need to develop PayPal solutions, I'd start there.  Maybe he was talking about [Payments Pro Payflow edition](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/paypal-payments-pro-payflow-edition) that requires you to code in Java or .net

Comment: Yeah the programmer I spoke with told me it could be program in C++ or java... I've should added java to the question...thanks for the hints.

Comment: In principle it has to be a replacement and a totally customized website for effiency. interfacing with paypal may be easier but has compromises to be done. Thanks for your help...

Comment: _"In principle it has to be a replacement"_ this will be **very hard** to do well, and more importantly to do _securely_. If you're intending to handle card payments, you'll need to read up on the PCI DSS. Interfacing with an existing payment provider will be orders of magnitude simpler than trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 3):

PayPal has a myriad of SDKs and solutions for you to integrate it into your website, and not tied to one language. You can write a PayPal-enabled website in PHP, Python, or even Java or C++ if you’re feeling particularly masochistic.

It’s just HTTP calls—passing a command from your web server to PayPal’s, and knowing how to interpret the callbacks to update your database record as paid, cancelled etc.

Comment: Ok I get it. But for more control I guess it has to be written in C++ or Java. Isn't it? I am saying this without having a clue of what is paypal doing behind the scenes but I wish to have as much control as I can, and I have been told by a robot(robot programmer) that is the way to do it.. thanks for your answer.

Comment: So you don’t know anything but making assumptions any way? I don’t know what you mean by “more control”—I’ve built various e-commerce systems using PayPal as a payment gateway in PHP. I don’t think I’d have gotten any more “control” if I’d opted for something like C++ or Java.

Comment: I did not assume anything. I was actually asking... Well apparently you don't know either if you'd have more control in PHP or C++...

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about? Define "control", because one programming language doesn't give you more "control" over using another programming language.

Comment: To be more concrete have you ever build a e-commerce system where users are able to transfer money between them? if yes I would be thankful that you give me the name of the website. "Control" mean a system where you can take the decision where the cash flows come and go.

Comment: I’ve built lots of e-commerce systems. Not one to send money between users, but all you’d need to do is change the “business” parameter sent in your HTTP call. But you’d know that if you read the documentation and stop insulting people trying to help you.

Comment: Ok so you've never built... ok. Let me point out that you started the hitting by the way.

Comment: I merely pointed out you were making assumptions without research, as evidenced by this sentence from you: “I am saying this without having a clue of what is paypal doing behind the scenes”. Don’t say things if you don’t know what you’re talking about and dismiss those that do.